# Use dominated convergence theorem to show: $\lim_{\ n \to \infty} \| f \ 1_{[n,n+1]} \|_1 = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Consider the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $\mathbb{R}$.
Given that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ is integrable,

**Ik would like to show the following using the dominant convergence theorem:**

$$\lim_{\ n \to \infty} \| f \ 1_{[n,n+1]} \|_1 = 0$$

**I started as follows:**
$$\begin{align}
\| f \ 1_{[n,n+1]} \|_1 &= \int_\mathbb{R} |f \ 1_{[n,n+1]}| \, d\lambda \\
                        &= \int_\mathbb{R} |f \ 1_{[n,n+1]}| \, d\lambda 
\end{align}$$

$f_n = |f \ 1_{[n,n+1]}|$ is dominated by  $|f|$, because $|f \ 1_{[n,n+1]}| \leq |f| $ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and |f| is integrable, because if $f$ is integrable, then absolute value of $f$ is also. We can apply dominant convergence:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\ n \to \infty} \| f \ 1_{[n,n+1]} \|_1 &=\lim_{\ n \to \infty}\int_\mathbb{R} |f \ 1_{[n,n+1]}| \, d\lambda \\
                        &= \int_\mathbb{R} \lim_{\ n \to \infty}|f \ 1_{[n,n+1]}| \, d\lambda \\
                        &= \int_\mathbb{R} 0 \, d\lambda \\
                        &= 0
\end{align}$$
But I feel like I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Everything you did is fine

Comment: If I were grading this, I would dock you a couple of points for missing details at the end. You should argue why $f$ goes to zero a.e. at infinity. (If even just referencing a result that shows this.)

Comment: $|f|I_{[n,n+1]} \to 0$ is so obvious I wouldn't deduct points for that.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Problem is that you have to _assume_ that's what OP is implying based on what they've written as a proof. They don't actually state that anywhere.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean. He never explicitely mentioned this. Another nitpick, you talk about $x \in \mathbb{R}$ but never there is an $x$ in a statement.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Yeah my apologies! Should have clarified a little better. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is correct but looks overcomplicated. Here is how I would write it.

You must show $$\int |f|I_{[n,n+1]}d \lambda \to 0$$

But you have $|f|I_{[n,n+1]} \to 0$ pointwise, $|f|I_{[n,n+1]} \leq |f|$ for all $n \geq 1$ and $\int |f| d \lambda < \infty$, so by the dominated convergence theorem we can conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct and you mentioned all the important arguments, I see no problem here.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int\limits_{\mathbb R} f\,d\lambda = \sum_{n\,\in\,\mathbb Z} \,\,\, \int\limits_{\mathbb R} f\mathbf 1_{[n,n+1]} \, d\lambda
$$
The series converges absolutely because $\|f\|_1<\infty.$ The terms of a convergent series approach $0.$

Comment: Justifying switching integral and sum also needs dominated convergence, so not sure if this is easier.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta : I'd have cited Fubini's theorem to justify that, but "needs" may be too strong a word in this case. The fact that it can be done that way doesn't mean that's the only way to do it. $\mu(A) = \int_A f\, d\lambda$ defines a measure $\mu$ that is countably additive. Countable additivity of that measure is what this is.

Comment: Alright, but proving that also uses limit theorems. But it gives another approach.